# Rails 3 User Authentication (User Types)

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3

Are there any particular rails user authentication gems or plugins that are well-suited for multiple user types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) has a good way to set up multiple roles, perhaps it's something you could use.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for authenticating multiple types of user, like you want to store admins in one table and users in another?  If that's what you want, then I agree that [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is the way to go.

If you want to use one user model and implement roles, then I think a combination of [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) would be a great choice.